# Use Windows credentials in MS access

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering if it is possible to use Windows10 credentials to identify someone and give access to a form in MS access using VBA. Just like Chrome ask you for your windows passwords in order to show you it's password list.
Thanks

Comment: Try `Environ("UserName")`.

Comment: Need a Users table with user names and permissions. Then code uses Environ("USERNAME") to grab Windows user name and lookup permissions in table and act accordingly. For instance, users can be classed as "admin" or "user" and only admin gets to see button on form that opens a certain form. This is a fairly common topic. When you have some code with issue, post question.

Comment: Thanks, that works for getting the user name and it will do the job. But I was just wondering how to make windows ask for the password. Like chrome does.

Comment: You either have to assume that the user logged into Windows is the same user accessing your database (if not then there are probably other security issues at your company). Or else you have to implement your own security/permissions within the Access database,

Comment: Windows has already asked for password when user logged on to computer. If you want Access to also ask for a password then you have to code that. Access security is a common topic. Do you know about 'shift key bypass'?

Comment: @JobouJP What your are expecting may it is not possible to `MS-Access`. You are expecting to ask password then match it with windows login password what is stores to widows system. So, far I know `MS-Access` can't access windows credentials.

Comment: You can read this [article](http://www.accesssecurityblog.com/post/Securing-Access-databases-using-Active-Directory.aspx).